# Binding to the Title of a Window does not always work

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, window, relativesource

I need to databind two `TextBlock`s to the `Window.Title` property. The first one works via:

```
RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}"
```

But the second one does not (it's deeply nested within a button `ToolTip`).

How can I change the second one to make it also display the `Title` of the `Window`?

```
<Window ...>
   <Border ...>
      <Grid ...>
         <Grid ...>
            <!-- TEXTBLOCK BELOW WORKS -->
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="18px" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" />
            <Button Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent"
                    ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="0" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="60000">
               <Button.ToolTip>
                  <ToolTip x:Name="helpButtonTooltip" Width="240" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0">
                     <!-- TEXTBLOCK BELOW DOES NOT WORK; HOW CAN I MAKE IT WORK? -->
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="18px" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool tip is displayed in a popup and is not part of the same visual tree as the button or your window. Consequently, `RelativeSource` and `ElementName` bindings do not work.

What you can do is bind the window title to the [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=net-5.0) property of your button and then bind the `Text` of the tool tip `TextBlock` to the `Tag` property of the [`PlacementTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tooltip.placementtarget?view=net-5.0) (which is the button).

```
<Button Tag="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
   <Button.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}}"/>
      </ToolTip>
   </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```